# my sed command is not working inside shell script

Tags: sed

I have a sed command something like this to comment out a particular line based on a particular pattern:

```
sed -e '/$OLD_VERSION/ s/^#*/#/' -i /ws/usernam/workspace/scripts/raw-vobs-config-spec
```

Here we need to comment out the line containing `$OLD_VERSION`.  I have passed `$OLD_VERSION` as a parameter in my shell script.

Comment: Is it working in console ?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: `a sed command something like this` != `this sed command`. Guess which one is required to help solve a problem you have with a given command. The command you posted will **NOT** do what you want no matter where you call it from.

Answer (score 1):

When you use single quotes in a shell, it prevents ordinary variable expansion, and so `$OLD_VERSION` will not expand.  Since you don't have any other characters requiring escaping, the fix should be as simple as using double-quotes:

```
sed -e "/$OLD_VERSION/ s/^#*/#/" -i /ws/usernam/workspace/scripts/raw-vobs-config-spec
```